# How to prove a solution of equation is rational if another one is rational number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The question is : $r$ is the solution of equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ and $r$ is a rational number, so there is another solution $s$, how to prove s is a rational number as well? I have no idea about it and I think that I shall prove it through $(x-r)(x-s)$ equals to the equation, but still no idea about it. Please help me a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Please add context - is this high school homework? Is this a first year uni course? Or is this a graduate abstract algebra course?

Comment: Do we know anything about $b$ and $c$?

Comment: I assume that additionally $b$ is rational. Then use the fact that $r+s=-b$.

Comment: Right:) otherwise, consider $p(x) = x^2 - (1+\pi)x + \pi = (x-1)(x-\pi)$.

Comment: we assume b and c are real number and I am the first year in universe.

Comment: We know that $-b = r+s$ and $c = rs$.

Comment: You say you have no idea how to think about it but in the very next sentence you say you'll prove it through (x -r)(x - s).  That's an idea.  What happens when you multiply (x - r)(x -s)?  $x^2 +(-r-s)x + rs = x^2 + bx +c $  what does that tell you about rs  and c?  Especially if r is rational and c is also rational?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a very easy way of going about this.

$r$ must be in the form $\frac uv$.

If $x=r$ is the solution to $x^2+bx+c$, then we have:

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$$

Which we know one of such must be rational.

Lets go along with the following:

$$r=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$$

We know that since $r$ is rational, then it is in  the form $\frac uv$:

$$\frac uv=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$$
We can easily see that $\sqrt{b^2-4c}$ must be rational for the numerator to be rational, which must be true because the denominator is rational and the whole fraction must be rational.

If $\sqrt{b^2-4c}$ is rational, then:

$$\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2=\frac{-b-R_0}2=\frac{R_1}2=R_2$$

Where $R$ represents a rational number.

So both roots must be rational.

Answer (score 0):

Since $r$ is rational, say $r=p/q$, where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, and $p,q$ are relatively prime.

Then if $s$ is also a root, we have $x^2+bx+c=k(x-r)(x-s)\implies ax^2+bx+c=x^2-(r+s)x+rs$.

Thus,
$$-(r+s)=b$$
$$rs=c$$

Using the last equation, we see that $s=c/r=\frac{cq}{p}$. So $s$ is only rational if $c$ is rational.